# R3 Corda Example Nodes Not Working

Tags: blockchain, corda

I'm currently trying the Hello World! tutorial (part 1) and followed every step except I upgraded the Gradle distribution URL to 4.3 so the Cordapp would work. It initially opens up with 5 nodes then 2 remain: for PartyA and PartyB. The problem is the Corda interactive shell does not open and these are the items remaining on my screen. Any help is appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/au2mp.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSvHk.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running the nodes with `runnodes`, each node creates its own terminal windows. If a node fails, it will auto-close its terminal window, preventing you from seeing the resulting message.

Instead of starting the nodes using `runnodes`, try navigating into one of the nodes' folders, and starting the node directly using `java -jar corda.jar`. If the node fails to start, the error message will appear in the terminal without closing it. This will allow you to diagnose the problem.